# User Input into Variable Containing Special Characters and Wild Cards not passing into Powershell Command

Tags: powershell, variables, input, wildcard

I have been stuck on this problem for awhile now and cannot seem to find a solution that works. I have a situation where I cannot get a variable, created from user input for multiple file extensions, to work inside of a command in Power Shell. In the script below, if I manually enter the arguments for the file extensions using wild cards, and enclose each one in quotes separated by a comma, it works, but if I try to substitute the $Extensions variable created from the read-host function by typing the exact same string, it does not work. Two code examples below: The first one works, but the second one does not.

```
#This works
$AllVariables = Get-Variable
function CompareVariables {
Compare-Object (Get-Variable) $AllVariables -Property Name -PassThru | Where -Property Name -ne "AllVariables"
}

#write-host 'Enter Extensions'
#$Script:getsomeinput = read-host

$Script:File_Path = "E:\Play Station1 Roms\_1 New Downloads"
#$Script:Extensions = "$getsomeinput"
$Script:Output_Path = "R:\"
$Script:Output_File = "List.txt"

$Script:numfilescount = (Get-ChildItem -path "$File_Path" -recurs -include "*.bin", "*.pbp").count
$Script:ListFiles = Get-ChildItem -path "$File_Path" -recurse -include "*.bin", "*.pbp" | format-list | Out-File -Append -FilePath $Output_Path$Output_File

CompareVariables
""
'{0}{1}' -f $Output_Path,$Output_File
write-host "$Output_Path$Output_File"
""
read-host
#*******************************************************************************************


#This Does Not work when "*.bin", "*.pbp" is typed as input into the variable from the console.
$AllVariables = Get-Variable
function CompareVariables {
Compare-Object (Get-Variable) $AllVariables -Property Name -PassThru | Where -Property Name -ne "AllVariables"
}

write-host 'Enter Extensions'
$Script:getsomeinput = read-host

$Script:File_Path = "E:\Play Station1 Roms\_1 New Downloads"
$Script:Extensions = "$getsomeinput"
$Script:Output_Path = "R:\"
$Script:Output_File = "List.txt"

$Script:numfilescount = (Get-ChildItem -path "$File_Path" -recurs -include "$Extensions").count
$Script:ListFiles = Get-ChildItem -path "$File_Path" -recurse -include "$Extensions" | format-list | Out-File -Append -FilePath $Output_Path$Output_File

CompareVariables
""
'{0}{1}' -f $Output_Path,$Output_File
write-host "$Output_Path$Output_File"
""
read-host
```

I have tried a variety of things. I have tried splitting strings. I have tried putting the input from the variable into an array. I have tried string formatting, single quotes, double quotes... everything I could find online to output the data from the input into a format that the variable would pass to the command correctly and to no avail. I declared all of the variables in the script as script to avoid scope issues while trouble shooting, and I the added the compare variables functions so I could see the output and form of all of the variables created during the test.

I was able to get the $Extensions variable to show the correct format, with wild cards and all, several times using several methods, but I could never get that input to work in the command even though the output inside the variable appears to be correct. Please help, as I am a novice. This is the last obstacle in my way stopping me from finishing my script.

Comment: Working `-include "*.bin", "*.pbp"` (correct `[string[]]` parameter) but  if you set `$Extensions = "*.bin,*.pbp"` then use `-Include ($Extensions -split ',')` because the `-include "$Extensions"` is wrong…

Comment: Thank you so much. That finally worked. Changing the structure as you explained and typing in the extensions with no spaces and separated by the comma allowed the split function to do its magic. I know that many new-comers to powershell probably struggle with this issue, but finding the simple solution is actually quite difficult, so I appreciate your input and for taking the time to help me figure out this problem. It would be nice if the powershell gods would update their software to handle variables like that in an easier fashion someday.